# Kommasetzung vor wie

Tags: standard-german, comma, written-language

Hey habe noch mal eine Frage bzgl. Kommasetzung:

"Mit Beginn einer Erkältung sinken die Leukozyten und erreichen teilweise Konzentrationen, wie sie bei anderen Krankheiten beobachtet werden."

oder ohne komma?

"Mit Beginn einer Erkältung sinken die Leukozyten und erreichen teilweise Konzentrationen wie sie bei anderen Krankheiten beobachtet werden."

Answer (score 3):

Hier wird ein Nebensatz eingeleitet, weshalb ein Komma benötigt wird.

Comment: Siehe [Amtliches Regelwerk](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#), § 74.